# ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 13 is different from 2)

Tags: python, machine-learning

```
variables = df.iloc[:,:13]
results = df1.iloc[:,14:]
regression = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regression.fit(variables,results)
print(variables.shape,results.shape)
input_values = [2,2]
prediction = regression.predict([input_values])
prediction = [round(x,2) for x in prediction[0]]
print(prediction)
```

The error is ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 13 is different from 2).
The variables shape is (51, 13) (51, 11).

This is the multiple-output regression, when I do the prediction part, there exists an error. But I don't know how to fix it, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have 13 features in your input but in the prediction part, you are only passing 2 values. You have to pass an array of dimensions (x, 13) where x belongs to some natural number. If it solves your question then kindly give the green tick and upvote.